# Can you rewrite this snippet without goto

Tags: c++, refactoring, goto

Guys, I have the following code that is inside a big while loop that iterates over a tree. This is as fast as I can get this routine but I have to use a goto. I am not fundamentally against goto but if I can avoid them I would like to. (I am not trying to start a flame war, please.)

The constraints:

1. The `current=current->child()` is expensive (it's a `shared_ptr`) so I'd like to minimize the use of that operation at all cost.
2. After the operation `current` should be the last child it found.
3. `cnt` must count each child it encounters.
4. cnt++ will be replaced by some other operation (or several operations) and should only appear once :)

the code:

```
insideloopy:
cnt++;
if ( current->hasChild() )
{
    current = current->child();
    goto insideloopy;
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry guys, originally forgot to mention cnt++ should only appear once. It will be some kind of operation on the node, and should thus only be there one time. I'm also trying to avoid making that another function call.

Comment: You should specify which language

Comment: looks like someone needs help on their homework...

Comment: not homework :) ,.. actual work :) had brain freeze

Comment: how is shared_ptr expensive ?

Comment: it seems as if you're iterating over the nodes of just 1 branch... not over a tree.

Comment: I did some profiling comparing the tree iteration with raw pointers and shared pointers.

Without going into great detail here are some quick numbers:

20000 iterations over 1 tree:
Raw Pointers : 150 ms
Shared Pointer unoptimized implementation: 1400ms
Shared Pointer optimized: 577ms.

Shared_ptr are slower as they do reference counting and every time you do current=current->child() a lot of stuff happens in the background compared to a simple raw pointer assignment.

So for the benefits they give I'll take the slow down.

Comment: @xtofl, this is just a small piece of the iteration code. Which correctly only iterates one branch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
insideloopy:
cnt++;
if ( current->hasChild() )
{
    current = current->child();
    goto insideloopy;
}
```

I love infinite loops.

```
while (true) {
   cnt++;
   if (!current->hasChild()) break;
   current = current->child();
}
```

Of course you can do it in many other ways (see other answers). do while, put the check in the while, etc. In my solution, I wanted to map nearly to what you are doing (an infinite goto, unless break)

Comment: Fantastic! Good work. I just couldn't get my brain in action this morning.

Comment: This one is a little better than LorenVS' infinite loop version, because of the inverted logic. I still think my comma operator use is warranted and more readable though :P

Comment: @unknown: didn't you said, that you trying to avoid extra if?

Comment: doesn't the while(true) pretty much become an unconditional jump?

Comment: I too prefer the reversed if logic here - but I feel LorenVS 6 minute earlier version was robbed of the accepted answer rep. ;) He'll have to settle for my measly +1.

Comment: Sorry LorenVS, I am not sure who was first as you ended up editing your answer (after I clarified the requirements). What does the 'answered time' reflect,.. first post or last edit?

Comment: imho, the break is just a hidden goto.

Answer (score 26):

### Original answer

Assuming this is C or C++:

```
while (cnt++, current->hasChild())
{
    current = current->child();
}
```

I'm not a big fan of the comma operator usually, but I don't like repeating myself either :)

### Updated 'fun' answer

After learning that `cnt++` is actually some multiline operation, this particular syntax would be less than ideal. Something more along the lines of your accepted answer would be better.

If you want to be really funky, this would also work:

```
do 
{
    cnt++;
} while (current->hasChild() && (current = current->child()));
```

Now I feel really dirty though, with my abusing the short circuiting on the `&&` operator :)

### Sane answer

Exercises in compactness aside and striving for readable code, I'm forced to conclude that one of the existing answers is best suited (I'm just including this for completeness' sake):

```
while (true)
{
   cnt++;
   if (!current->hasChild()) break;
   current = current->child();
}
```

The `while (true)` will be optimized by the compiler into a regular infinite loop, so there is only one conditional statement (if you care about that).

The only thing going against this solution is if your node operation was a long piece of code. I don't mind infinite loops so much, as long as I can see where they terminate at a glance. Then again, if it were really long, it should be a function anyway.

Comment: In this case, works very well, and you can pack everything on a single line.

Comment: that is very compact indeed! :) and would work for the example but the cnt++ will be multiple operation in the actually application. Not sure what that will look like.

Not a big fan of the comma operator either.

Comment: @Ron: with multiple statements, your accepted answer is probably the best solution. Too bad you didn't put that in your original question :P
@Stefano: I'd split it over 2 lines I think. Some code style nazis don't like omitting braces though :(

Comment: Sorry about that. This was my first question here and I never expected it to be such a race to get the first answer!

Comment: There's always a run on these. Nice compact question, short answer. Easy points :)

Comment: I'm sure I'll come up with another one :)

Answer (score 18):

```
cnt++;
while(current->hasChild())
{
   cnt++;
   current = current->child();
}
```

EDIT:

If you only want cnt++ to be in your code once:

```
while(true)
{
    cnt++;
    if(current->hasChild())
       current = current->child();
    else
       break;
}
```

Comment: cnt++ should only appear once.

Comment: you can avoid if statement by using do while loop, instead.

Comment: i'm trying to avoid the extra if,.. keep it fast :)

Comment: Its true, this seems more natural to me, but who knows, I might have a really strange coding style :)

Comment: I personally try to avoid `while (true)` if at all possible.

Comment: Very close to the solution that I ended up accepting. Not sure who was first though, tried to upvote your comment though.

Comment: > I personally try to avoid while (true) if at all possible

That's funny,.. maybe we could you a goto!!

Comment: @Thorarin. they are not necessary evil, provided they finish, and they are kept small.

Comment: @Stefano: I agree, and I don't get out of my way to avoid them. Often they are the best solution, especially in C# which I usually work in. However, with the comma operator available, it is easily avoided in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `break` to get out of the loop in the middle of the code:

```
while (true) {
   cnt++;
   if (!current->hasChild()) break;
   current = current->child();
}
```

Comment: @xtofl: Yes, but one that has a well-defined and easy to find target. That makes a lot of difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (current->hasChild())
{
    cnt++;
    current = current->child();
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(cnt++ ; current->hasChild() ; cnt++) {
   current = current->child();
}
```

Comment: So? The comma operator could be used here if the cnt++ has to expand to multiple statements. Not that it would be a good idea...

Comment: if cnt++ is multiple statements, it should perhaps be a function rather. And you can easily do for(cnt++,i = 0,current=firstChild(); ...; ...) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd investigate the possibility of making `current->child()` return NULL when it has no child if it doesn't already -- that seems the best possible result and leaving it undefined in this case seems error prone -- and then use:

```
for (; current; current = current->child())
{
    cnt++;
}
```

Comment: The current->child() call is expensive compared to the hasChild() call. hence I want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Is current->child() expensive even if hasChild() return false?  If so, I'd simply wrap it with an hasChild() precondition.

Comment: That would violate the second constraint however: *After the operation current should be the last child it found.*

Answer (score 0):

No break statements:

```
notDone=true;
while(notDone){
   cnt++;
   if ( current->hasChild() ){
       current = current->child();
   } else {
       notDone=false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Avoiding break is overrated, imo. Are you going to be proving correctness for this algorithm? Will break make it that much harder?

Comment: Break won't make it harder - it will introduce two possible code paths to the first statement after the loop, which requires analysis of both prior states. But the code above has two possible code paths to the loop-end where the condition is re-checked ("if" clause and "else" clause), which requires analysis of both prior states. "else" is just goto in disguise ;-)